# How to send an array of test-cases to PHPUnit willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls

Tags: php, arrays, unit-testing, phpunit

I am trying to send a pre-calculated array of test cases into a mock to be returned on consecutive calls - similar to the map function. However it takes a list of arguments, not an array.

My array is already generated by a fixture-generator and may be of variable length.

What I want to do is something like this, but of course this causes it to return the entire array on the first call.

```
// In a test case:
$processorMock
    ->method('process')
    ->willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls(
        $fixtureLoader->getProcessorScenarios() // how to explode this?
    );

// class FixtureLoader pseudocode:
function getProcessorScenarios(){
    return [ 
       [ $param1, $param2, $param3 ], // case 1
       [ $param1, $param2, $param3 ], // case 2
       ...
       [ $param1, $param2, $param3 ], // case N
    ];
}
```

I want to destructure the returned array from the fixture loader, using list() or some var-args exploding language construct like "..." in other languages, but couldn't find anything native that worked.

I do have what feels like a hacky method, which I will post as an initial answer Q&A style.  I want to know if it's the best method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A friend suggested an alternative available in [PHP 5.6](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php) - the "splat" operator or elipsis (...) although it doesn't seem to have an official name in PHP, but is a form of destructuring like the ["spread" operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) in Javascript ES6.

While I haven't tested this (as my app is currently locked to PHP 5.4 due to environmental constraints), it should therefore work simply thus:

```
$processorMock
    ->method('process')
    ->willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls(
        ...$fixtureLoader->getProcessorScenarios()
);
```

This is definitely the sweeter alternative I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I found works is using the `call_user_func_array` function to expand the array into parameters.

```
    call_user_func_array(
        [$processorMock->method('process'), 'willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls'],
        $fixtureLoader->getProcessorScenarios());
```

This feels nasty, and breaks up the fluent definition of the mock. I'm guessing it will have downsides such as brittleness for the future.

I'd like to find a sweeter alternative before it becomes the copy-pasta template solution!

Update:

I've since found I need to wrap some of the parameters in asserts, as they are more complex types, e.g. classes.

```
// class FixtureLoader pseudocode:
function getProcessorScenarios(){
    $param1 = PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::IsInstanceOf('MyApp\Model\Thingumy');
    $param1 = PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::isInstanceOf('MyApp\Model\Whatsit');
    return [ 
       [ $param1, $param2c1, $param3 ], // case 1
       [ $param1, $param2c2, $param3 ], // case 2
       ...
       [ $param1, $param2c3, $param3 ], // case N
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to use `willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls` to get the outcome you desire.
The `@dataProvider` will take an array of test data and feed it into your test one batch at a time, for as many times as necessary to get through the data.

I wasn't 100% clear on whether you have a variable number of tests, or a variable number of parameters.

**Example for 3 variables:**

```
/**
 * @dataProvider getProcessorScenarios
 */
function testcase($param1, $param2, $param3) {
// use the variables

}

function getProcessorScenarios() {
    return [ 
       [ $param1, $param2, $param3 ], // case 1
       [ $param1, $param2, $param3 ], // case 2
       ...
       [ $param1, $param2, $param3 ], // case N
    ];
}
```

A way you could do this with a changing number of variables would be to pass the variables *as an array* into the test function instead of individually, But I don't know how you could use them if you don't know how many are coming, so I don't think this is a valid solution.

**Example with changing number of variables:**

```
/**
 * @dataProvider getProcessorScenarios
 */
function testcase($params) {
// use the variables which are in an array

}

function getProcessorScenarios() {
    return [ 
       [ 'params' => [$param1, $param2, $param3 ]], // case 1
       [ 'params' => [$param1, $param2, $param3 ]], // case 2
       ...
       [ 'params' => [$param1, $param2, $param3 ]], // case N
    ];
}
```

Comment: Hi Ben welcome to S.O. Yes the dataProvider is useful for iterating over test data, but I think (it's been a while) in my case above I am responding to multiple mock-calls within one invocation of some function of the S.U.T. so this all happens within one single test case invocation (probably using a data provider, as I use them extensively). Sorry - that wasn't clear in my question.

Comment: I can't remember exactly, but what's probably happening is I'm calling a service function under-test which itself iterates over DB rows, like users or something, then calls the mocked sub-system for each one. So because the system-under-test processes lists, I needed the test mock-expects to also process the same list.